# how to get ApplicationInfo when received PACKAGE_REMOVED broadcast?

Tags: android, android-intent

What i want to do is to update local database when an application is removed or added.
But when i got PACKAGE_REMOVED,I found it's unable to get its ApplicationInfo any more. It just throws namenotfound exception.Any suggestions?thanks.

```
if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED")) {  
            try{
                    final String packageName = intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart();
                    ApplicationInfo app = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
                    final String fname = app.sourceDir;
                    String md5 = Util.Md5(fname);
                    dbm.deleteApk(md5);
                } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package has already been removed when the Intent `PACKAGE_REMOVED` is broadcast. At that point it is too late. You'll need to save the information you want BEFORE that. You can do that either when the package is installed, or you could have your application run on boot and collect the `ApplicationInfo` for all installed packages and save that that in a database or whatever. When the user deletes a package, you'll get the `PACKAGE_REMOVED` broadcast and you can find the information you want in your local database.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);
```

public static final int GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES
Added in API level 3

Flag parameter to retrieve some information about all applications (even uninstalled ones) which have data directories. This state could have resulted if applications have been deleted with flag DONT_DELETE_DATA with a possibility of being replaced or reinstalled in future.

Note: this flag may cause less information about currently installed applications to be returned.